# Repa vs Mutable vector performance

Tags: haskell, repa

I have coded two implementations of an algorithm to calculate all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix. One implementation uses the REPA library

https://github.com/felipeZ/Haskell-abinitio/blob/master/Science/QuantumChemistry/NumericalTools/JacobiMethod.hs

While the other implementation uses mutable Vectors and the ST monad

https://github.com/felipeZ/Haskell-abinitio/blob/master/Science/QuantumChemistry/NumericalTools/JacobiMethodST.hs

The algorithm is the Jacobi method which description can be found at 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_eigenvalue_algorithm

I have tested the two implementations using 100 matrices of dimension 100 x 100, running the code sequentially and I have found the following times:

```
                  REPA      Mutable Vectors

Total time(s)    6.7            28.5

GC (s)           0.2             1.2
```

The Jacobi Algorithm requires an iterative updating of some of the matrix entries, meaning that most of the matrix is left untouched between iterations.
 Therefore I would have guessed (erroneously) that the cost of copying a new matrix for each iteration in the REPA implementation will be bigger than the cost of mutating the matrix using the monad ST, because as far as I understand REPA doesn't mutate the array but makes a copy of it.

It is REPA fusing all the operation and avoiding to copy of a new array in each iteration? or it is something else?

Can someone please comment on this result?

Comment: I don't think the repa developer(s) are very active these days. I'd be curious to see how well yarr (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yarr) performs but sadly I don't have time at the moment to investigate this myself.

Comment: Could you please describe your implementation in more detail? In particular, _repa_ distinguishes unboxed `U` and delayed `D` arrays, and mixing these two properly seems to be important for good performance. I wonder which ones and where you used. -- For having fast `ST` code it's often important to use tight loops and prevent memory allocation inside (which I guess _repa_ takes care of internally). And I guess copying data around a few times isn't that costly on modern machines, provided they're in one block to take advantage of memory caching.